# Finding pattern with newline using regex in Java 7

Tags: java, regex, newline

I am writing a regular expression being used to search through files and find the following pattern:

```
{@link ClassName} provides
 *
```

I have written this expression so far using `java.util.regex.Pattern`:

```
private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\\{@link [a-zA-Z0-9]*\\} provides\r\n \\*");
```

However, this is not finding any matches. I have got as far as finding the pattern without the newline, but trying to search for the pattern with the newline and '*' character is proving difficult.

How else can I check if there is a newline followed by a '*'? I've also tried '\r' and '\n' on their own in the pattern.

Note: I'm using Java version 1.7.0_25

**Update**
Showing my code (left out the bit where I print out the matches to console):

```
public class PatternSearcher
{
    private static final String JAVA_FILES_GLOB = "glob:**/*.java";
    private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\\{@link [a-zA-Z0-9]*\\} provides\r\n \\*");

    @Test
    public void checkForPattern() throws Exception
    {
        final StringBuilder filesWithPattern = new StringBuilder();

        final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(JAVA_FILES_GLOB);

        Files.walkFileTree(SourceCodeTestUtil.getErsCoreDir().toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
        {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file, final BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
            {
                if (pathMatcher.matches(file))
                {
                    for (final String line : Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset()))
                    {
                        if (MY_PATTERN.matcher(line).find())
                        {
                            filesWithPattern.append(file).append("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `"\\{@link [^}]*\\}\\s+provides[\r\n]+\\s*\\*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That didn't seem to find any matches either, unfortunately

Comment: It [should find the match](https://regex101.com/r/SF2GnN/1). Show the code. Are you using `.matches()` instead of `.find()`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am, yes. I've updated my post to show the code.

Comment: Use `.find()` and replace `if` with `while` to find all occurrences.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I am using `find()` already. I am using `matches()` for checking the file path.

Comment: Ok, you are reading the file *line by line*. You cannot expect a regex that is searching for a line break to find a match if you do not pass *multiline* input to the regex engine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Understood, thank you. I'll try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following pattern

```
"\\{@link \\w+\\} provides\\n \\*"
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with this:

```
private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\\{@link [a-zA-Z0-9]*\\} provides(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n) \\*");
```